# jQuery getting needed value from returned objects

Tags: jquery, json, object

I am having some issues with getting the needed value from using **$(this)** within my code below:

```
....
open: function() {
    console.log('Popup is opened');
    console.log($(this).get(0).src);
},
....
```

I've also tried:

```
....
open: function() {
    console.log('Popup is opened');
    console.log($(this)[0].src);
},
....
```

But I do not seem to have the correct structor in order to get that value.

The *objects* of **this** are:

```
{
"0": {
    "isIE7": false,
    "isIE8": false,
    "isLowIE": false,
    "isAndroid": false,
    "isIOS": false,
    "supportsTransition": true,
    "probablyMobile": false,
    "popupsCache": {

    },
    "items": [{
        "el": {
            "0": {
                "jQuery111108245181320528183": 1
            },
            "context": {
                "jQuery111108245181320528183": 1
            },
            "length": 1
        },
        "src": "http://linkishere.com/Dolphin.jpg",
        "type": "image",
        "index": 0,
        "parsed": true,
        "img": {
            "0": {
                "jQuery111108245181320528183": 20
            },
            "context": {
                "jQuery111108245181320528183": 20
            },
            "length": 1
        },
        "hasSize": true,
        "preloaded": true
    }],
 Etc etc.....
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Item object contains `src` property and its belongs to `Item` then you should use

```
console.log(obj[0].items[0].src);
```

here is **[Fiddle Example](http://jsbin.com/qisageqoquve/1/edit)**

Comment: You got it. Thanks Anant!

Answer (score 1):

if you have above json structure then

use `this["0"]["items"]["0"].src` not `$(this)[0].src`

or

```
this[0].items[0].src
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$(this).attr('src')` not `$(this)[0].src`

Answer (score 0):

if your this object is correct as you described. you can access src without jquery as follow:

```
 console.log(this[0].items[0].src);
```

Comment: TypeError: this[0] is undefined

Comment: your this object has some problem or your representation of this object is not correct. please try to log with 

     console.log(JSON.stringify(this));
if code implementation is in jquery event scope, this object can confused with jquery object